# AngularJS : Directive not able to access isolate scope objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am trying to put some default values in my directive with Isolate scope. Basically, I need to do some DOM manipulations using the scope object when my directive is bound. Below is my code:

Controller:

```
angular.module('ctrl').controller('TempCtrl', function($scope, $location, $window, $timeout, RestService, CommonSerivce) {

$scope.showAppEditWindow = function() {
    //Binding the directive isolate scope objects with parent scope objects
    $scope.asAppObj = $scope.appObj;
    $scope.asAppSubs = $scope.appSubscriptions;

    //Making Initial Settings
    CommonSerivce.broadcastFunction('doDirectiveBroadcast', "");
};
```

Service:

```
angular.module('Services').factory('CommonSerivce', function ($rootScope) {
return {       
    broadcastFunction: function(listener, args) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(listener, args);
    }
};
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('tempDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope:{
        appObj:'=asAppObj',
        appSubs: '=asAppSubs'
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {},
    controller : function ($scope,Services,CommonSerivce) {         
        //Broadcast Listener 
        $scope.$on('doDirectiveBroadcast', function (event, args) {
            $scope.setDefaults();
        });

        $scope.setDefaults = function() {
            //Setting Default Value
            alert(JSON.stringify($scope.appSubs)); //Coming as undefined            
        };
    },
    templateUrl:"../template.html"
    };
});
```

Custom Directive element:

```
<temp-directive as-app-obj="asAppObj" as-app-subs="asAppSubs" />
```

Now, the issue is that while trying to access the isolate scope in the default method inside directive, I aam getting an undefined value whereas the data is coming and is getting bound to the DOM. How can I access the isolate scope in the broadcast listener and modify the directive template HTML? Is there another wasy for handling this?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is: at that time angular ***does not update its bindings*** yet.

You should not access your variables like this, try to use angular js binding mechanism to bind it to ***view*** (by using $watch for example). Binding to parent scope variables means you're ***passive***, just listen for changes and update ***other variables*** or ***your view***. That's how we should work with angular.

If you still need to access it. You could try a workaround using $[timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)

```
$scope.setDefaults = function() {
    $timeout(function () {
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.appSubs)); //Coming as undefined  
    },0);          
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hsGnC/)

It's better to use $watch

```
 angular.module('ctrl', []).controller('TempCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
         $scope.appSubscriptions = "Subscriptions";
         $scope.appObj = "Objs";
         $scope.showAppEditWindow = function () {
             //Binding the directive isolate scope objects with parent scope objects
             $scope.asAppObj = $scope.appObj;
             $scope.asAppSubs = $scope.appSubscriptions;

         };
     });

     angular.module('ctrl').directive('tempDirective', function () {
         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             replace: true,
             scope: {
                 appObj: '=asAppObj',
                 appSubs: '=asAppSubs'
             },
             link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

             },
             controller: function ($scope, $timeout) {
                 $scope.$watch("appSubs",function(newValue,OldValue,scope){
                     if (newValue){ 
                         alert(JSON.stringify(newValue)); 
                     }
                 });
             },
             template: "<div>{{appSubs}}</div>"
         };
     });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hsGnC/1/)

By using $watch, you don't need to broadcast your event in this case.

Comment: @Akhilesh Aggarwal: You should use $watch for this. Check out a similar problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142409/angular-directives-and-scope/19204970#19204970

Comment: @Khank To: This is even better :). Any particular reason why the 'watch' definition should be added inside 'link'. I tested and it works under 'controller' also.

Comment: @Akhilesh Aggarwal: In your case, I think you should use $watch inside `controller`. As controller should contain your logic and link function should only care about making a dynamic connection between model and view

Comment: @KhanhTO: According to the angular docs for [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive): "Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link."

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the isolated scope variable is not available when the directive's controller first instantiates but probably its available when you need it for a following event such as: within a function bound to an ng-click

its just a race condition and the object doesn't arrive exactly when  directive's controller loads