# Angularjs: In a custom directive I need to read argument passed with ngClick method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my custom directive, in order to set the right template, I need to be able to use an argument that has been passed like so:

```
ng-click="loadTabContent('socialnetwork')"
```

In my controller I have something like this:

```
$scope.loadTabContent = function(passedArgument){
    $scope.content = PostsResource.query();
    // below I'd like to attach the above argument onto $scope object like so
    $scope.networkCalled = passedArgument;
}
```

Then in my directive I'd do this:

```
// linker function
var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
    // does NOT work
    element.html( getTemplate(scope.networkCalled) );

    // does work, provided I have type="somename" on my directive element in HTML
    element.html( getTemplate(attrs.somename) );

    $compile( element.contents() )(scope);
}
```

I suspect that the value of the argument is not attached to the $scope object in time, so it's not available when I need it. Is $apply or any other built-in function supposed to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I left out an importan piece of my directive I believe:

```
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true,
            link: linker,
            scope: {
                content: '='
        }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code (e.g. the directive definition object).

Comment: the assignment should be instant. check your scope, the directive could be using a different scope.

Comment: I've just updated my question, see Edit at the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're binding your directive `scope.networkCalled` with a controller's scope property. Unfortunately,  at that time angular **does not update its bindings** yet.

When you use isolate scope, remember to declare your `networkCalled` property:

```
scope: {
      content: '=',
      networkCalled:'='
}
```

And bind the property in your html:

```
<div your-directive network-called="networkCalled"></div>
```

Try $watch to get notified when the binding is updated:

```
var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){

    scope.$watch("networkCalled",function (value){
       if (value){
          element.html( getTemplate(value) );

          $compile( element.contents() )(scope);
       }
    });
  }
```

For more information: [AngularJS : Directive not able to access isolate scope objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153430/angularjs-directive-not-able-to-access-isolate-scope-objects/19194393#19194393)

Comment: BTW, I tried your proposal and it doesn't work. It doesn't work even if I attach the value to the $scope as string AND outside my loadTabContent() method, like this: $scope.networkCalled = 'googleplus';

Comment: My previous comment assumed your answer prior to your edits - now it does work! However, this seems like overcoding to me. Any chance we can simplify it? Because the same stuff has been added to: button/ngClick, directive HTML markup, $scope in controller, directive's return function, then $watch portion of linker function...
Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me getting it work!

Comment: @developer10: angular was designed with binding mechanism. It makes sense to follow angular binding mechanism by using $watch in this case because whenever your property changes, you will be notified to update your view accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again, I will mark this answered by you. However, should anyone come across this in the future and have a better solution (maybe next versions will bring something new to the table) is welcome to post if possible!

Comment: Let me ask you something else. How can I invoke (mimic) my loadTabContent('networkname') method so I get the default tab loaded when page opens, without a user having to click the first tab? Thank you!

Comment: @developer10: You need to provide more information, I don't get how your code works to switch tab at the moment.And it's better to ask this as a separate question so that you could draw more attention from other people, too. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254814/op-is-annoying-me-by-asking-more-questions-based-on-a-single-question-which-was

Comment: @developer10: I'm not sure how your code works, maybe you could call your `loadTabContent('networkname')` in your controller when you initialize your controller scope.

Comment: I understand. Here's the new question, maybe you can help. Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722730/angularjs-when-page-loads-for-the-first-tab-trigger-the-method-that-is-norma