# Can you emit event from Controller in one module to Directive Controller in another module?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller "MyController" and a directive "MyDirective" in separate modules "app" and "directiveModule" respectively. DirectiveModule has been injected into the angular.module of "app".

The issue I am having is as part of "app", I have a controller that emits an event "TEST" that the controller for the directive does not pick up. How can I successfully get the directive of its own module to catch the emit? Is this possible? (Note: I tried $scope originally, then used $rootScope, but both do not make a difference.)

My controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$emit('TEST');
});
```

My directive:

```
directiveModule.directive('MyDirective', ['$rootScope', 'MyService',
function($rootScope, MyService) {

return {
   restrict: 'E',
   controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('TEST', function() {alert("Event Caught")})

}]};
}];
```

UPDATE: It looks like my directive has not initiated by the time the event is broadcast. Is there a way to make it such that I could "wait for directive to instantiate" as opposed to waiting an arbitary "1000" ms or another alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only case your directive needs to catch that event is to get some initial data ***depending on*** the `MyController` because if your directive is independent of the `MyController`, you don't need to catch that event, just initiate the directive independently.

My solution is using $watch to get notified when the ***initial data*** from the  `MyController` is ready.

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {}; //initialize the data, this data could be fetched from an ajax
});

directiveModule.directive('MyDirective', ['MyService',
function(MyService) {

return {
   restrict: 'E',
   controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.$watch("data",function(newValue,OldValue,scope){
             //do your work here when data is changed.
        });  
    }]};
}];
```

In case you use isolate scope in your directive:

```
directiveModule.directive('MyDirective', ['MyService',
    function(MyService) {

    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope : {
           directiveData:"=", 
       },
       controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch("directiveData",function(newValue,OldValue,scope){//watch on the directive scope property
                 //do your work here when data is changed.
            });  
        }]};
    }];
```

Your html may look like this:

```
<my-directive directive-data="data" /> //bind isolate scope directive property with controller's scope property.
```

I think below questions are some similar cases like this:

- [AngularJS : Directive not able to access isolate scope objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153430/angularjs-directive-not-able-to-access-isolate-scope-objects/19194393#19194393)
- [AngularJS : directives and scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142409/angular-directives-and-scope)

Answer (score 3):

all modules injected into main module share same rootScope. `$emit` however travels up the scope tree, you need `$broadcast`.

If you `$broadcast` from `$rootScope` it will be received by all active scopes so in directive could actually use `$scope.$on` and wouldn't need to inject `$rootScope` just for the purpose of using `$on`

Similarly  if directive is descendant of the controller, could also broadcast from controller scope

Answer (score 2):

You can. Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vrZgnu?p=preview

A side note: if you try to communicate to children element that is lower in DOM tree, you should use `$broadcast`. `$emit` is used to communicate with parents elements ("up" direction).

But your true problem might be that when you tried to emit the event, the directive might not be initiated yet. I used `$timeout` service to wait 1000ms to broadcast the event.

#### Update

If you don't want to wait a arbitrary 1000ms, you can let your directive `$emit` "ready" event to inform controller that it's ready. Then broadcast from the controller.

Also removed the 1000ms in this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/GwrdIw?p=preview, everything still works. But I don't think this is a reliable solution.

Comment: That appears to be the problem... Is there any way I could prevent waiting 1000ms and simply just wait until the directive has initiated?